# How can jestjs test a function that uses performance.now()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, jestjs, performance.now

I'm writing a jestjs test for a ES6 class that uses `performance.now()`. But it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to user `perf-hooks` globally from the `jest.config.js`? Or a way to mock `performance` and override it with eg `Date`?

I've tried overriding performance on `classToTest.js` with `Date` but since it uses `performance`already on import that doesn't work.

Simplified examples:

**classToTest.test.js**

```
import ClassToTest from "./classToTest";

test("constructor works", () => {
  expect(new ClassToTest()).not.toBeNull();
});
```

**classToTest.js**

```
const timer = performance.now();

class ClassToTest {
...
```

The output from jest is `ReferenceError: performance is not defined`.

Comment: did you import `performance` in your classToTest.js? `const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')`

Comment: Yes that works. Also changing to Date.now() works. But I'd like to be able to test the source code as it is and runs in it's environment, not adapt it to the test environment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. Let's forget about your test for a moment. Assuming `ClassToTest` code works and is a black box for us, how can it use `performance` without importing it in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `Jest` test environment is `jsdom` (the default) then it provides a browser-like environment that includes [a mock for `performance` on the global `Window` object](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/865ad590454dd345521722184bc298b32fa40810/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L233-L235), so `performance.now` will be defined automatically.

If your `Jest` test environment is `node` then you will need to provide your own `performance` global.

That can be done by adding a setup file to the [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) array:

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [ './setup.js' ]
}
```

...and within the setup file defining a global `performance`:

**setup.js**

```
global.performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! I had to upgrade my jest installation to make it work though, seems like the setupFilesAfterEnv is a pretty new addition.

Comment: Great answer and explanation. Instead of adding it globally it can also be imported in files where needed like `const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')` (no installation required as it's part of node).

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2024**

With the latest jest version performance.now() can be tweaked using [fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks).

Here is an example:

```
jest.useFakeTimers({
    now: new Date("2024-02-07T00:00:01.123Z"),
});
const start = performance.now();

jest.advanceTimersByTime(1234.5678);
const end = performance.now();

expect(end - start).toBe(1234.5678);
```